# No Wireless N on Intel 5100

Tags: wireless, intel

I've got a D-Link DIR-655 router and a laptop with a Intel WiFi Link 5100 network card.

I'm running Ubuntu 11.4 x64 - 
`uname -a`:

```
Linux fraekkert 2.6.38-11-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 29 19:02:55 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I've configured the router to allow both wireless g and n, and another laptop is connecting over n, but this laptop wont.

I remember that wireless N were temporarily disabled when Natty came out, but I can't figure out if anything have happened since then, so I guess the memory leak must've been resolved by now.

This is the output from `lshw`:

```
*-network
            description: Wireless interface
            product: WiFi Link 5100
            vendor: Intel Corporation
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
            logical name: wlan0
            version: 00
            serial: 00:24:d6:65:0d:d0
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlagn driverversion=2.6.38-11-generic firmware=8.83.5.1 build 33692 ip=192.168.0.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
            resources: irq:45 memory:e3500000-e3501fff
```

And the output from `dmesg | grep iwl`:

```
[   20.943539] iwlagn: Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux, in-tree:
[   20.943544] iwlagn: Copyright(c) 2003-2010 Intel Corporation
[   20.943691] iwlagn 0000:01:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[   20.943703] iwlagn 0000:01:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   20.943750] iwlagn 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) WiFi Link 5100 AGN, REV=0x54
[   20.966066] iwlagn 0000:01:00.0: device EEPROM VER=0x11f, CALIB=0x4
[   20.966071] iwlagn 0000:01:00.0: Device SKU: 0Xb
[   20.966370] iwlagn 0000:01:00.0: Tunable channels: 13 802.11bg, 24 802.11a channels
[   20.966466] iwlagn 0000:01:00.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[   25.869658] iwlagn 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 8.83.5.1 build 33692
[   25.879814] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
```

Edit:

The interface is working, but only in g-mode. If I turn my access point to n-only, I can't connect to it.

The output of `rfkill list`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: please can you add the output of `rfkill list`. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Examine the following folder `/etc/modprobe.d`

If there is a file in there called something like `intel-5300-iwlagn-disable11n.conf` or `intel-5100-iwlagn-disable11n.conf` then edit the file

i.e.

```
sudo nano [filename.conf]
```

edit the line that says

```
options iwlagn 11n_disable=1
```

to

```
options iwlagn 11n_disable=0
```

Save and reboot.

[source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1701477)

Comment: There's nowhere in my /etc/modprobe.d/ folder where the 11n_disable option is mentioned. I'll try to add the 11n_disable=0 line and reboot to see if anything changes. Thanks.

Comment: ok - if I understood that source link correctly - if the two named conf files (intel-5300... / intel-5100...) dont exist in the folder then create one/or the other/both and add the "options" text into the file.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see MSI there somewhere--I think your laptop's probably MSI, so...

I have an MSI x400, and it has also an Intel WiFi Link 5100. The first time I installed Ubuntu 11.04-amd64 (beta 2), the wi-fi also didn't work. I think, back then, it didn't tell if the hardware enable/disable were used. Try to check if the hardware button for the wireless is involved somehow. Mine was just turned off by the hardware button.

Comment: Thanks, but the hardware is on and working in g-mode. I just cannot connect to the access-point with wireless n.