# Can't connect to a specific WiFi network (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop and I can't connect to a specific WiFi networks.
I managed to connect to others wifi networks in the past without any problem, and other devices (another laptop with Windows 7 and some Android smarthphones) were also able to connect to this WiFi network. Furthermore, this laptop can connect to the same router through the ethernet cable. So, as a resume, the problem is just between this particular device and this particular WiFi network.

Any hint about what may be happening?

I already tried solutions proposed on these questions but it didn't worked:

[Can't connect to specific wifi network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286915/cant-connect-to-specific-wifi-network)
[Can't connect to specific WiFi with 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313330/cant-connect-to-specific-wifi-with-13-04)

It seems that I don't have the iwlwifi but the wl instead. I also tried following those steps but replacing "iwlwifi" with "wl" but nothing.

**Edit:**

http://paste.ubuntu.com/9656647/

Comment: Please run the script http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108 and copy the contents of the wireless-info.txt and use http://paste.ubuntu.com to upload results and paste the link because without it all I can figure is, is that you have a broadcom wifi chip and tried a solution that is specific to intel chipsets

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9656647/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From what I found on ubuntuforums.org you should

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

reboot
and you may need to blacklist b43 and/or ssb
but you can try this after a reboot one line at a time and see if you are able to connect

```
sudo modprobe -r b43
sudo modprobe -r ssb
```

If you are able to connect only with using the modprobe -r b43 then `echo "blacklist b43" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/b43.conf`

If it also took the modprobe -r ssb to connect then do both `echo "blacklist b43" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/b43.conf`
and `echo "blacklist ssb" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/b43.conf`
and wifi should connect

Comment: It worked! I didn't needed to blacklist b43 nor ssb. Thank you very much!