# Unable to connect to specific wifi with ubuntu

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, internet

I have recently changed my router and started facing problem while connecting to my home wifi using ubuntu 16.04. So what happens is, all other nearby wireless networks are shown while unable to see my home wi-fi. So I change my wireless network name to some different random name and I can see it in networks list. But after restart of system I can't see it again and I have to change the wireless network name again to use the network.

I can connect to my wireless network using windows [its a dual boot system] and with my phone. I have formatted the system too recently in hope of resolving the error, however I am unable to resolve it so far.

Already referred to this question [Can't connect to a specific WiFi network (Ubuntu 14.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567799/cant-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-ubuntu-14-04) and tried switching the drivers but was of no help.

**Update** Same issue happens with Elementary OS and Mint too. Also on other ubuntu machines too.

**Edit** Network Diagnostic report while connected to wifi, I will paste the report after booting the system again when I am not connected.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 29 Jan 2017 16:22 IST +0530

Booted last: 29 Jan 2017 00:00 IST +0530

Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-59-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 6 17:47:47 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Kernel driver in use: wl

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet [1969:1090] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell AR8162 Fast Ethernet [1028:055e]
    Kernel driver in use: alx

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2897 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

dell_wmi               16384  0
dell_laptop            20480  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 dell_wmi
dcdbas                 16384  1 dell_laptop
wl                   6365184  0
cfg80211              565248  1 wl
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
wmi                    20480  3 dell_wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  40960  4 i915,dell_wmi,nouveau,dell_laptop

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF1]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]>  
          inet addr:192.168.0.4  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::c7d5:8e63:c1bf:5a59/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5828493 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:816899
          TX packets:3791649 errors:163 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3591678341 (3.5 GB)  TX bytes:812680341 (812.6 MB)
          Interrupt:16 

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"Dlink22"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.427 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'Dlink22' [AC1]>   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      2629     1  0 Jan27 ?        00:00:17 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Broadcom Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         wl
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 6.30.223.248 (r487574)
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0/net/wlp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlp2s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Dlink22
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       a42ad140-79a9-43e4-ad68-4da46047667d
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     72 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{1}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   a42ad140-79a9-43e4-ad68-4da46047667d | Dlink22
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.4/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1485752028
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 192.168.0.4
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       routers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.0.255
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 192.168.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.0.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::c7d5:8e63:c1bf:5a59/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Qualcomm Atheros
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        AR8162 Fast Ethernet
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         alx
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:03:00.0/net/enp3s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID         BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  * 
Dlink22      <MAC 'Dlink22' [AC1]>  Infra  4     2427 MHz  54 Mbit/s  71      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2  yes     * 
Ragamadhuri  <MAC 'Ragamadhuri' [AC2]>  Infra  4     2427 MHz  54 Mbit/s  60      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2  no        

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Dlink22]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Dlink22 | type=wifi | permissions=user:vinit:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Dlink22
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp3s0    no frequency information.

wlp2s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 38 : 5.19 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 42 : 5.21 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 46 : 5.23 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      2   APs on   Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)

wlp2s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'Dlink22' [AC1]>
                    Channel:4
                    Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
                    Quality=58/70  Signal level=-52 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Dlink22"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 88ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'Ragamadhuri' [AC2]>
                    Channel:4
                    Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
                    Quality=46/70  Signal level=-64 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Ragamadhuri"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 17832ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[wl]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-59-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
srcversion:     4DDC5FCDB1E30F7DFDCA530
depends:        cfg80211
vermagic:       4.4.0-59-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           passivemode:int
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-59-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     FD4B9DA2F385F0531B5CB0B
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-59-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[66655.049290] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[66655.049302] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[66661.351867] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[66661.471984] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[88209.681414] ERROR @wl_dev_intvar_get : error (-1)

########## wireless info END ############
```

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that your machine has a bay to install a wifi card into in addition to one that may already be on the motherboard?Sounds crazy,but this is the case on my HP laptop.When I removed the extra wifi card and checked the bios to make sure the built in card was activated,I had Wifi.

Comment: Well its working just fine with windows on same machine, its a dual boot machine...I doubt such thing can be issue.

Comment: Would be helpful to know the things you have tried to diagnose.  For example, if connection is using inet6, have you tried setting up interface to only use inet4?  Are there any errors in the log files related to this?  /var/log/*

Comment: Its inet4 connection...regarding log files, i am not sure which I should look into. Also connection don't show up...then I doubt what would be in log file then

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.

Comment: Hey David, thanks for the response, I have attached the network diagnosis report with the question, I will restart the machine and share the report again.

Comment: What is the wireless channel in your router. Change it to 1-11.

Comment: Yeah channel was set to auto ranging between 1-13, however I have fixed the channel to a specific one, but can you please help me where the supported channels are mentioned in the network info?