# Ubuntu unable to connect to specific networks

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, network-manager

I have a dual booted system [(specs)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Frm9a.jpg). Since yesterday, I am unable to connect to college wifi on ubuntu. It works fine on windows. I have tried 
[this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567799/cant-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-ubuntu-14-04) method on askubuntu but it is not working. I am able to connect to hotspot which I made on mobile and to the same wifi using tethering via mobile.

The only thing that I remember is that yesterday, when I was working on windows, I had to turn off the windows firewall for some time. Later, I re enabled it.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to restart the network service at first. Had this myself with the Schoolnetwork and for me that worked. I have dual booted KDE Neon and Windows.

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

When that does not work right away, maybe you try to reconnect completely afterwards.

Comment: Tried that...not working :(