# Can't connect to wifi while traveling overseas Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, laptop

I have an issue and can't connect to any wifi in Ukraine. I'm using a gigabyte 2442 laptop and running Ubuntu 14.04 on it only. Every time I turn on the laptop I have to go to land settings to turn off the Hotspot and after I turn it off sometimes it takes 2 times to get the list of available wifi spots. And I click on my wifi, for some reason it just doesn't want to connect. I press the connect button and it just ignores me. There is no action what so ever.  I'm stuck and I don't know what to do. Is that a chip problem. The laptop is made in thaiwan and my one was bought in Canada.  I don't know if that's a usefully information or not but I can't understand what the matter. Anyways if anybody knows what's the problem or had the same issue please let me know how I can solve it. The model of the router is tp-link 150mbps wireless n adsl2+ modem router 
And I'm a fairly new user ID the Ubuntu OS

I've tried a method that I've looked up on this web site and it didn't work. Know Lan is not showing any network at all since I've put all those codes in my terminal is it possible that I've blacklisted some settings on my wifi?

Below is the list of codes that I've typed in to my terminal.

> ```
> sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
> ```
>
> reboot and you may need to blacklist b43 and/or ssb but you can try
>   this after a reboot one line at a time and see if you are able to
>   connect
>
> ```
> sudo modprobe -r b43
> sudo modprobe -r ssb
> ```
>
> If you are able to connect only with using the `modprobe -r b43` then
>   `echo "blacklist b43" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/b43.conf` If it also
>   took the `modprobe -r ssb` to connect then do both `echo "blacklist
>   b43" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/b43.conf` and `echo "blacklist ssb" |
>   sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/b43.conf` and wifi should connect

The post link is

[Can't connect to a specific WiFi network (Ubuntu 14.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567799/cant-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-ubuntu-14-04/947154?noredirect=1#comment1506398_947154)

Comment: The router's model is seldom relevant. Troubleshooting starts with the WiFi device. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: OK the first command gave me a lot of information what do I have to look at to troubleshoot? At the end it says kernel driver in use iwlwifi.   And kernel modules iwlwifi

Comment: And what should I edit in my question? I'm fairly a noob with this

Comment: I've tried a method that I've looked up on this web site  and it didn't work. Know Lan is not showing any network at all since I've put all those codes in my terminal is it possible that I've blacklisted some settings on my wifi?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command. It is one command, not two.

Comment: Better yet, follow the instructions [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/44179) and edit that information into your question. Thanks!