# Can't connect one type of modem that is Huawei HG552e (Ubuntu 15.04) - I tried all solutions on the forum, but didn't work -

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, 15.04

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04, My computer cannot connect to a specific WIFI network, but it's connecting to this network using an ethernet port. Also when I open my computer with Windows 7, it can connect this network with WIFI.

The information about the WIFI: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10890679/

I've check out this topics, but I couldn't solve my problem:

(1) [Can't connect to specific WiFi with 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313330/cant-connect-to-specific-wifi-with-13-04)

(2) [Can't connect to a specific WiFi network (Ubuntu 14.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567799/cant-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-ubuntu-14-04)

(3) [Can't connect to specific wifi network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286915/cant-connect-to-specific-wifi-network)

How can solve this problem? Thank you so much.

**Edit: I've tried another modem that is Huawei HG552e, also I can't connect this modem. Is it possible to block this type of modem, how can fix this problem?**

Comment: How are you trying to connect ? with networkmanager applet ? What is the security of the wifi AP ?  What are the possible errors ?

Comment: I assume it is _test_wifi_ that you are trying to connect to. Is this a router over which you have administrative privileges? I suspect the result will be better if the router is set to WPA2-AES and not TKIP. Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying with network manager applet. The security of the wifi AP is "WPA2 - PSK"  The applet says that "Disconnect, you are now offline" It try to connect for a time and then it can't connect the network.

Comment: You'ra right, I'm trying to connect "test_wifi". There is no privileges, to be sure I did reset the modem.  I've just tried, there is no choice as only WPA2 so I've selected "WPA2 - PSK" and AES but unfortunately, it didn't work @chili555

Comment: I've tried another modem that is Huawei HG552e, also I can't connect this modem. Is it possible to block this type of modem, how can fix this problem?

Comment: @Eclairing could you find a solution? I have a HG552e modem in my home and I can't connect to it. Other Wi-Fi APs and modems are working.  I can connect to this modem via Windows7, my android phone, and an Iphone but can't connect via Ubuntu.

Comment: @sedran  Unfortunatelly, I couldn't find anything. If you find any solution, Could you inform me, please? Thanks.